# How to parse json in android

Tags: android, json, database, retrofit, rest

**https://api.mojilala.com/v1/stickers/trending?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC**

```
data class RootApi(val data : List<AllData>)
data class AllData(val images : ImageSticker)
data class ImageSticker(val fixed_height : ActualImage)
data class ActualImage(val url : String)
```

is this the correct POJO class or not according to given api

Comment: Don't expose key publically it can be misused.

Comment: it's Public API :)

Comment: API is public but are you sure about key?

Comment: https://github.com/mojilala/sticker-api   yes its public

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, hide your API key in the question. Coming to generating data classes of JSON. I would suggest you use the following Plugin

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-

And no that is not the correct data class. Infact it is very big. I can't even paste it all in the answer. Use the plugin. Paste the JSON response and generate yourself.

Comment: it's a public API and free also :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @che10 you should end up with the below:

```
data class Data(
    // Assuming you are using Moshi https://github.com/square/moshi
    // Use @SerializedName("data") if you're using Gson
    @Json(name="data")
    val stickers: List<Sticker>,
    val meta: Meta,
    val pagination: Pagination
)

data class Sticker(
    val designer: String,
    val id: String,
    val images: Images,
    val is_animated: Boolean,
    val rating: String,
    val tags: List<String>,
    val url: String
)

data class Pagination(
    val offset: String,
    val total: Int,
    val total_count: Int
)

data class Meta(
    val msg: String,
    val status: Int
)

// Different fields but of two types so we can reuse the classes
// Difference between AnimatedImage and StillImage is the two webp fields
data class Images(
    // Animated images
    val fixed_height: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_height_downsampled: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_height_medium: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_height_medium_downsampled: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_height_small: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_width: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_width_downsampled: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_width_medium: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_width_medium_downsampled: AnimatedImage,
    val fixed_width_small: AnimatedImage,
    // Still images
    val fixed_height_still: StillImage,
    val fixed_height_medium_still: StillImage,
    val fixed_height_small_still: StillImage,
    val fixed_width_still: StillImage,
    val fixed_width_medium_still: StillImage,
    val fixed_width_small_still: StillImage,
)

data class StillImage(
    val url: String,
    val size: Int,
    val height: Int,
    val width: Int,
)

data class AnimatedImage(
    val url: String,
    val size: Int,
    val height: Int,
    val width: Int,
    val webp: String,
    val webp_size: Int
)
```